# No me carga el background-image

Tags: html5, css3, visual-studio, php5

Estoy teniendo problemas para cargar un fondo en mi página de inicio y desconozco el motivo. He intentado meter la etiqueta  tanto en la propia página, como aludir a ella dentro de la etiqueta body o html y al final la he dejado como sigue, pero sin novedad:

```
.fondo{
    background-image: url(../assets/coche-portada.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

después en mi página hago una llamada a mi archivo css a través de link.

y asigno en el `body` un `div` con `class="fondo".`

Comprobando en el explorador en modo desarrollador, me carga el archivo css pero no la imagen. Y la ruta es la correcta, porque en el visual studio al hacer ctrl+click en la ruta metida dentro de url() me abre la pestaña con la foto.

Es una página ".php".

Agradezco cualquier ayuda y muchas gracias!

Comment: Por cierto, en caso de querer mostrar la imagen insertada en un div, como se haría? Por otra parte, cuando le meto el atributo "opacity" no me lo acepta tampoco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solo debes agregar background y no background-image ya que esta ultima no te acepta los atributos no-repeat center center fixed

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Extrañamente al declarar las propiedades cada una por separado, me funciona. Así que doy por cerrado el post.

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
```

}

```
.fondo{
background-image: url('../assets/coche-portada.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
```

}

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te solucionó el problema